# How to extract all text if their is a html tag in b/w the text segment of a webpage using scrapy in python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
    <td>
        <ul>
           <li>Some_text1<sup id="cite_ref-33" class="reference"><a 
               href="#cite_note-33">some text_link</a></sup> Again some_text2
               <sup id="cite_ref-34" class="reference">
               <a href="#cite_note-34">[34]</a></sup> and some_text3 again
          </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
```

I've tried this and but can't get `[34]` and `some_text3` and if there are more tags like `<p>`, `<div>` and `<span>` which contains text inside. Is there a way to extract all the text inside `<li>` no matter how many tags are there?

```
for x in response.xpath('./ul'):
    u = list()
    for y in x.xpath('./li'):
        s = y.css('li ::text').get()
        t = y.xpath('./a/text()').get()
        if t is not None:
            s = s + t
        print (s)
```

The output should be `Some_text1  some text_link Again some_text2[34] and some_text3 again`.
The output my program getting is `Some_text1 some text_link`

Comment: Why can't you simply use `x::text` directly, which should retrieve all the text under ul.

Comment: thanks buddy i used `xpath(string())`